# Is it possible to overload auto ? (c++)

Tags: c++, dynamic, types, overloading, auto

I 'm just wondering , is it possible to overload an auto type , using several late-specified return type ?
What I want to do is to use a dynamic type argument in my constructor class to 
call a generic function returnValue() which be able to return the dynamic type using a dynamic constructor. I've just some few ideas , like using virtual inheritances or templates but I'm not sure so I ask to get any advices , thanks ( it seems to be harder than c# to get dynamic type in c++ )

```
#pragma once

class AutoType
{
public:
    AutoType();
    ~AutoType();
    auto returnValue()->float(*)[1];
    //auto returnValue()->int(*)[1];
    //static const auto staticAuto;

    /*
    int returnValue(){
        return 1;
    }
    float returnValue(){
        return 2;
    }
    long returnValue(){
        return 123;
    }*/

};
```

Comment: Ok , what's the problem ? I'm just asking , and I get all this negative feedback , why don't you just give me revelant answers , please , thanks

Comment: Does this line of code `auto returnValue()->float(*)[1];` compile?

Comment: I think that I will start to stop posting questions on Stack Overflow . It's like everytime I'm asking question I've got this negative feedback , so maybe is not the right place for me ...

Comment: Am I missing something? I don't see any *negative* feedback, just people confused about your question

Comment: Yes, of course it compiles , just check this link  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409852.aspx

Comment: The links title is "Compiler Error C3551" - I am confused that you think it compiles

Comment: You can write auto-statements functions returning defined parameters ( ex : int(*)[1]; ) theses parameters are called " late-specified" , in opposition of "early specified" parameters notion

Comment: I cannot get your code to compile. The link you posted is titled "compile error", I am just confused

Comment: @EdHeal: `auto returnValue()->float(*)[1];` is a function that returns a pointer to a one-element C-style array of floats, according to the MSDN link. It most certainly does compile, and its return type can be assigned to `float (*a)[1];`

Comment: @EdHeal : I just edited my code , so now you can try on your own , but on my side it compiles.

Comment: I'm assuming "negative feedback" means the score of -1? If you can ask higher quality questions then less people will downvote your questions and more people will upvote them. Mainly that's to do with how easy the question is to understand, not the technical content of the question.

Comment: I can easily understand what you said about higher quality question but I'm just wondering some specific aspects about c++ language , and instead of getting revelant answers , I just get a negative feedback without any consistent explanation . If I'm asking on Stack Overflow is just to learn and perform my coding skills , and honestly I get a sufficient coding level to work on standalone OOP... this is just my curiosity to learn everyday new coding practises which put me here , I just expected alternatives and explanations about possible ways to return / overload auto variables.. Thanks

Comment: @sachaamm: "If I'm asking on Stack Overflow is just to learn and perform my coding skills" I'd say your biggest problem is that your question was so confused that I couldn't even understand what you were asking for until I saw an answer. Not to mention your stubborn insistence on putting spaces before all punctuation marks. Those two combined tend to lead to downvotes.

Answer (score 4):

> is it possible to overload an auto type , using several late-specified return type ?

No.  You cannot overload a function/method based on its return type alone.  Only its parameters can be used for overload resolution.  What you are asking for will have to be solved using templates, or by returning a runtime variant type like [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/any.html).

Comment: @sachaamm What..? This answer is informative and, if anything, *positive*